# Why eclipse plugin doesnt start - log?

Tags: eclipse, logging, eclipse-plugin, startup

I have plugin that doesnt start(from dropins, with eclipse -clean), however its not even mentioned in

**workspace\.metadata\.log**

Is there any log that says why plugin doesnt start?

I think the problem is that too new API is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the Host OSGi Console?

[image]

Here are some tutorials/articles that will hopefully help you figure things out:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-osgiconsole/
- http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html